# How to center an object

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

How do I center an object in the form.

in the VCL I usually use

```
lblID.Left := (MainForm.Width div 2) - (lblID.Width div 2);
```

but the above code is not working in FMX because the **Width** of any object is **single** not **integer**.

I've tried the following but stil it does not center it perfectly

```
lblID.Position.X := (MainForm.Width div 2) - trunc(lblID.Width)  div 2;
```

Whats wrong ?

Comment: Also you can examine FireMonkey Layouts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `TPosition` property of FMX controls is stored in floating point, not integer, format.  There is no need to use integer division.

```
 lblID.Position.X := 0.5*(MainForm.Width - lblID.Width);
```

- [FMX : TPosition](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/FMX.Types.TPosition.X)

You should probably also review :

- [Arranging FMX Controls](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Arranging_FireMonkey_Controls),
- [FMX.Controls.TControl.Align](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.Align)

For example :

```
lblID.Align := alHorzCenter;
```

may give you want you want.  Adusting the `Padding` property will allow for vertical placement of the control while `alHorzCenter` will keep the control horizontally centered.